# how to show selected rows with check marks while updating the previously selected rows in UITableView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i tried like this...in cellForRowAtIndex()

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       static NSString *SimpleTableViewIdentifier=@"SimpleTableViewIdentifier";

      UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableViewIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableViewIdentifier];
   }
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text=[hardDependencyAlldataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return  cell;
}
```

and added below lines of code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath..

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

but,while updating the previous selected value,check mark is not showing onpreviously selected rows..any one can help in this issue..Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the previous selected value"?

Comment: thq..for u r response.. :)..

Comment: previously i selected rows from a table view...while selecting appearing check mark on selected rows...now i want to show agian check marks on previously selected rows before going to updation...

Comment: Have you refreshed the table view in between?

Comment: u mean  reload the table view ?...?

Comment: Tamim I updated my answer.Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need to do. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, instead of assigning `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` for all cells, assign it to none only for those cells which are not selected

Change the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to store the selected cell detail to an array

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
[self.selectedCellArray addObject:[hardDependencyAlldataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Now change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       static NSString *SimpleTableViewIdentifier=@"SimpleTableViewIdentifier";

      UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableViewIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
      {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableViewIdentifier];
      }
      cell.textLabel.text=[hardDependencyAlldataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      if (![self.selectedCellArray containsObject:[hardDependencyAlldataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
      {
          cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
      }
      else
      {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
      }
      return  cell;
}
```

Comment: my concern is ,i want to keep track of  lastSelectedRows with check mark for identifying lastSelectedIndexed values ,while populating the table view data....

Comment: thq Mr. Arun. :) ...but still i didnt get, previously selected rows with check mark in edit mode...

Comment: Sorry I missed a bit code. Please check my answer now with new updates

Comment: The mistake you were doing was you were reloading the table view which will reset selection style of all cells back to none. What we are doing now is saving the state of cell which is already selected and updating it to selected in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1):

I got it Tamim. Check the below answer.I tried sample project.It works fine.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableArray *arrProductSelection,*arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark;
  NSArray *arrayFetchFromDefaults;
  NSInteger lastSelectedIndex;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  arrProductSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPad",@"iPod",@"iTV",@"iWatch",@"iMac",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   arrayFetchFromDefaults = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
   arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayFetchFromDefaults];
   if(arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark.count == 0)
   {
      arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      for(int j=0;j<[arrProductSelection count];j++)
      {
        [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];
      }
   }
   [tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate reloadData];

}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return arrProductSelection.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *strCell = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
   }

   // lastSelectedIndex =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedRow"]; - Getting Last selected index row

   if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

   else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

   //    if (indexPath.row == lastSelectedIndex)
   //        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

   cell.textLabel.text = [arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
 }


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"selectedRow"];  //This is for Last Selected IndexPath Row

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   @try
   {
     CGPoint touchPoint = [cell convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
     NSLog(@"%@",arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark);
     if([arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark count]==0)
     {
        for(int i=0; i<[arrProductSelection count]; i++)
        {
            [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];
        }
     }
     if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"selected"];
     }
     else
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"deselected"];
     }

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark forKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
     [defaults synchronize];
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"The exception is-%@",exception);
  }
}

- (IBAction)actionGoPrevious:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: previously posted code was worked for me..but how should i deselect previously selected values...

Comment: I have done everything brother.Check my code once.You get everything.I implemented Select ,deselect and saving last selected row  and checking condition whether if last selected row index is equal to indexPath.row or not.Everything done in my coding brother.

Comment: Check it and tell me.

Comment: Compare two answer.Give tick for best useful answer.It should fulfill all your requirement.Select,DeSelect,Selected Index Row for showing when we come back.Everything should work.

Comment: hi varun..GM..yester code was fine..but it shows only one last indexed value...but i want to show muliple values with check mark..

Comment: hi user3182.. GM...but it shows only one previously selected index with check mark..but i want to show multiple selection with check mark was previously selected values

Comment: I updated my answer.Now it works for your requirement Tamim.